# Significato di "trettarì"

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Il sorriso dell'ignoto marinaio*, di Vincenzo Consolo, ho letto:

> Chinnici aveva fama per il **trettarì**. Sempre quello, da due anni, da quando mise piede a Cefalù. Si presentava al pizzicagnolo: pasta estratto ricotta 
>   pecorino caciocavallo tonno bottarga aringhe pescestocco... (moglie, 
>   tre figli e suocera a carico con fame d'allupati). Col pollice e l'indice tirava dal taschino l'argento bianco, glielo metteva sotto il naso fissandolo negli occhi. «Che fa, mi scangia?» gli diceva. «Vossia scherza?» gli rispondeva il pizzicagnolo. «Dove lo trovo il resto? Un'altra volta, dopo, dopo mi paga». La medesima faceva poi col carnezziere, il pescivendolo, il panettiere, l'acquaiolo, l'ortolano. S'approfittava financo dell'Ersilia, la vecchia che vendeva per le strade cicorie cacocciole asparagi finocchi babbaluci, 
>   secondo la stagione.

La mia domanda è: cosa significa "trettarì"? Non ho trovato questo termine in nessun dizionario. Si tratta di un vocabolo di origine siciliana? Potrebbe trattarsi di una moneta d'argento?

Comment: Il tarì è il nome di varie monete circolate nell’area del Mediterraneo. Ho trovato che anche molti ristoranti siciliani si chiamano i tre tarì.

Comment: @abarisone: Quindi si tratterebe di una moneta simile a [questa](https://www.lamoneta.it/topic/146778-filippo-iii-tre-tar%C3%AC-per-messina/)?

Comment: Penso si riferisca proprio a quella moneta

Comment: @abarisone: Beh... forse non esattamente quella perché la storia raccontata in questo romanzo ha luogo nell'Ottocento.

Comment: Ok, ma la moneta ha avuto una storia piuttosto lunga

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il trettarì o [tarì](https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar%C3%AC)  era un’antica moneta circolante nel Mediterraneo.

Ferdinando il cattolico reintrodusse questa moneta d’argento nel regno di Sicilia.

> In Sicilia il tarì aveva un valore diverso da Napoli. Carlo III
>   (1734-1759) coniò una serie di moneta con valore da 1/2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6
>   e 12 tarì. I multipli erano in argento a 916‰ mentre il titolo era del
>   908‰ per il 1/2 tarì ed il tarì. Quest'ultimo pesava 2,16 grammi ed
>   aveva un diametro di 19-20 millimetri. Il figlio Ferdinando, che in
>   Sicilia era il terzo con questo nome, coniò gli stessi valori del
>   padre nel periodo 1759-1816. Dopo quella data le monetazioni dei due
>   regni (Napoli e Sicilia) furono unificate e non ci furono più monete
>   separate per la Sicilia. L'ultima moneta siciliana denominata in tarì
>   fu quella da 12 tarì, battuta nel 1810. Era una moneta di 27,32 grammi
>   di argento al titolo di 854‰ e con un diametro di 38 millimetri. Al
>   dritto il busto corazzato con lunghi capelli e nel giro FERDINANDUS
>   III.D.G.REX; in esergo TARI 12. Al rovescio era raffigurata una grande
>   aquila circondata da una corona d'alloro. Nel giro UTR. SIC. HIER.
>   INFANS HISP. ([Re di] entrambe le Sicilie e Gerusalemme, infante di
>   Spagna). Nel contorno in rilievo SUB BONO PRINCIPE NULLA DOLO VIA.

Il "trettarì" o "tre tarì" era una moneta con il valore di tre tarì.

Comment: Penso che il trettarì fosse una moneta di valore "tre tarì".

Comment: Potrebbe benissimo essere

Comment: [Qui](https://www.lamoneta.it/topic/146778-filippo-iii-tre-tar%C3%AC-per-messina/) si parla di "un tre tarì": semplicemente cambia la grafia.

Comment: Si spiega di un famoso scrittore catalano che si è messo a vendere "duros" a quattro "pesetas".

Comment: La "pesseta" era la moneta che avevamo in Spagna prima dell'entrata dell'euro. Le monete di 5 "pesetas" erano chiamate "duros". La tua prima frase mi sembra qualcosa di simile a dire che i "duros" e le "pesetas" fossero la stessa cosa.

Comment: Ah, quindi il “trettarì” sarebbe un po' come in inglese _tuppence_.

Comment: Vedi anche [qui](https://issuu.com/coresi/docs/inside-n16/70) e [qui](https://books.google.es/books?id=KqtLAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA334&lpg=PA334&dq=%22il+tre+tar%C3%AC%22&source=bl&ots=-bYE7U16jm&sig=QG_sFa_a9ZJRiAD05K0DzwjJhyM&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwji7O3I2MnbAhWJtBQKHZFYCksQ6AEICzAA#v=onepage&q=%22il%20tre%20tar%C3%AC%22&f=false).

Comment: Io scriverei: Il tarì era un’antica moneta circolante nel Mediterraneo. [...] Il "trettarì" o "tre tarì" era una moneta con il valore di tre tarì.